# Running Firebase get() in a loop in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an android project and have encountered a problem in getting firebase firestore documents in a loop.

```
//getting the document snapshot out of the uIds
                        for (int i = 0; i < uidS.size(); i++) {

                            db.collection("items")
                                    .document(uidS.get(i))
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {

                                        if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                                            documentSnapshots.add(task1.getResult());

                                            if (documentSnapshots.size() == uidS.size()) {
                                                //Do something here...
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(this, "Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
```

> Here I have a ***uidS*** arraylist which contains all the id for getting the documentSnapshot from Firestore which then are added to a ***documentSnapshots*** arraylist.

Now the problem is that the loop finishes off before the **firestore task** is even started which makes the order of the loop's index in **Task** be kind of random, like:

```
Loop Index:0
Loop Index:1
Loop Index:2
Loop Index:3
Beyond the loop....
In firebase task with index 0 
In firebase task with index 2 
In firebase task with index 1  
In firebase task with index 3
```

I know it is the usual **asynchronous** behaviour of Firestore but I do not have any other way to structure the database or do anything else. How can i achieve this?

> Although, I know blocking the main thread may result in ANR but I have already checked for the internet connection speed in my code so all the documentSnapshots would take less than 2 seconds.

Is there any way I can make the task be executed first then *beyond the loop...* or any way to just make the order of index in **Task** be in order and not random?

Any help would be so much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so a solution for people, having the same kind of situation; would be **using another data structure** which does not depends upon the order of adding of elements.

> I used a Hashmap<String, DocumentSnapshot> to do the job with the string being the **UID**.

So, in whatever order they are added, we get the DocumentSnaphot by their respective UID, further.