# How to retrieve Users' comment with their profile image and name?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am make a social media app and I am using firebase firestore and cloud storage for my project. There is a comment button and if the user clicks the button he should be able to see every users' comments with their name and profile image.

This is my firestore database structure,

```
Users(Root collection)
                     |---- UID1([Document]User ID which generate by authentication)---[Fields-Name,Image,Age]
                     |---- UID2([Document]User ID which generate by authentication)---[Fields-Name,Image,Age]
```

---

```
Posts(Root collection)
                     |-----DOCID1(Fields-Post Title,Posted_UID,Post_Image)
                                                                         |----Comments(Sub-collection)
                                                                                                     |----1RANDOMDOCID(Fields-Commented_User_Id,Commented_Date,Comment)
                                                                                                     |----2RANDOMDOCID(Fields-Commented_User_Id,Commented_Date,Comment)
```

Alright, I need to populate these comments to a recycleview. I ll add my approach below,

```
  Query query = db.collection("Posts").document(CURRENT_SELECTED_DOC_ID).collection("Comments");
  PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .setPageSize(20)
                .build();
FirestorePagingOptions<CommentsI> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<CommentsI>()
                .setQuery(query, config, CommentsI.class)
                .build();
```

---

**Constructor**

```
public class CommentI {
String Commented_User_Id;
Date Commented_Date;
String Comment;
public CommentI(){
 //Empty constructor
}

public class CommentI(String commented_User_Id,Date commented_Date,String comment){
Commented_User_Id = commented_User_Id;
Commented_Date = commented_Date;
Comment = comment;
//------------------------------------------
public String getCommented_User_Id(){
return Commented_User_Id;
}
public Date getCommented_Date(){
return Commented_Date;
}
public String getComment(){
return Comment;
}
```

This is the usual way to populate items in recycleview. I can get these comments and date without any doubt, But I need to set the users' Image and name same time. this is the point where I had to stop my work until solve this. Please someone help :)

---

**Edit**

Here is my adapter and when we trying retrieve user info like this, it always reads the firestore document while scrolling up and down. For example - When I scrolling up and down(Just think i got 10 items in recyleview), I can see name and image refreshing everytime when scrolling from item 1 to 10 and from item 10 to 1. How to fix this?

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CommentIViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CommentI model) {
    holder.comment_textview.setText(model.getComment());
    holder.date_textview.setText(DateFormat.format("(yyyy-MM-dd)", model.getCommented_Date()));
    //getting UserID-------------
     String UserId = model.getCommented_User_Id();

    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference documentReference = rootRef.collection("Users").document(UserId);

     documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                   if (doc.exists()) {
                       String UserName = doc.getString("Name");
                       String UserImage = doc.getString("Image");
                       
           holder.commentor_name.setText(UserName);
                       holder.setProfile_image_view(UserImage);
                   }
               
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my bad. I suggested you to use the **Firebase User** object to store the *image URL* but you can only get the image of the current user (*which is not what you want*).

So storing in the database is needed. Now, as @Greg said that you have two approaches and I would also recommend having the second but if your use case is such that you need to have the first approach then here's what you do:

**1. Store the user's UID in the comments documents** (*which you have already done*).
**2. Get the comments of the particular post** (*which too, you have already done*).

Now, after this, you are getting the user's document in `onBindViewHolder` which is strongly **discouraged** as because your `onBindViewHolder` would be called many times in your `recyclerView` which would have performance issues and cost uprising.

By seeing your code, I am assuming that you are using **FirebaseUI** (*with which I have no experience*) but I think you should do this approach on your own like this (*I recently had such case and did like this*):

**3. Get the comments of the particular post and store it in something like an `ArrayList`**.
**4. Loop over the comments, get each user's documents and store them also in `Arraylist`**.
**5. Pass both the `ArrayLists` in your constructor of the adapter and then just set them up in `onBindViewHolder`**.

Now, when I was doing something similar like this, I got an unusual behaviour which you should see here (*if you are following this answer*) in my question (*with the answer given by myself*): [Running Firebase get() in a loop in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995951/running-firebase-get-in-a-loop-in-android)

Although, this would cost you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - add the Image & Name data to your Comments document (and still keep it in the Users document)

---

From the info above, I see two possible approaches:

1. Loop over the comments gathering the commenter's UID and then get the Users document for that UID and display the image within
2. When you create the Comments document in the first place, copy all relevant information about the User making the comment into the Comments document

Of the 2 approaches, I would strongly encourage #2.

When designing the data model for NoSQL (essentially - when determining what data to put into a document), think about your app and what you want to display on a given screen.  Try to put as much data in a single document for that given screen as possible to avoid reading additional documents.

This approach will feel "icky" to people coming from a SQL background.  In SQL land, we are all trained to eliminate data duplication via "data normalization".  Much of this stems from the origins of SQL in a world where storage space was "expensive".

In NoSQL land - such as Firestore - the base assumptions are

- storage is cheap
- writes (create/update/delete) are infrequent and "expensive"
- you fetch "documents" that are atomic >> *corollary*: there are no "joins"

In NoSQL land, we really don't mind data duplication.  We want to avoid fetching one document (Comment) and be required to do additional document fetches (Users).

Comment: yeah you are right, But what would happen if the user change his name or profile and this changes does not apply for previous comments right? It seems firebase is not suitable for app like social media or any other which users can comments, likes. Right?

Comment: @alex yes you are right. Although you can do all the tasks in any database the question which needs to be asked is - is that database efficient for your use case. You would be able to implement everything in Firestore too but it would not be efficient for your use case (atleast I don't think so) and the costs which you'll encounter would be above the sky. If the app is just a hobby-project to try out new things, sure you go ahead but if it's about production, I'll recommend not to go with Firestore.

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e  Yeah, I saw many comments like this, I really don't understand why google does not make firebase suitable for most cases. :D lets see what are firebase expert opinions about this

Comment: Actually, it's not about Firestore. It's about SQL vs NoSQL database. We just need to pick which gives us better performance and low cost for our use case.

Comment: I am still learning and I really don't have a knowledge about SQL Database, I started to read about firebase documentation since it is easy to use, but it seems I wasted my time :D

Comment: No, it's not that you have wasted your time. Don't underestimate NoSql databases! As I said, we just need to pick the perfect product for our use case. And both SQL and NoSql have their one pros and cons. And one best example for the use case of NoSql like Firestore which I can think RN is ecommerce inventory. So surely you can make full use of Firestore but in those cases where it is worth! Even, I'm currently working on a FireStore project.

Comment: Think through each data-change scenario.
For example: how often does a user actually change their name?  Does that update need to be reflected everywhere?  Does it make sense to worry about a Comment made 2 years ago? Sometimes yes, sometimes no....If I remember a comment was made to a post of mine by "Fred", but "Fred" has changed their name???

In a NoSQL scenario, you decide what data needs updating based on sound business criteria, make updates accordingly.  You might need to update hundreds or thousands of documents ... but the odds are that won't really be the case.

Comment: @GregFenton  haha you are right,  I tried this way because, I let the users  save posts(e.g-News or Important posts) also. In this case, It might be a problem, anyway thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e  Can you see my edit please. That is what i did for get the users info from User object. Just think if you are in the same situation, What would you do?

Comment: Check the answer.